# LinkedIn PHP sign on and fetch user's information

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Does anyone know to to sign into LinkedIn using php and fetch user's data
without entering verifying numbers for authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [OAuth](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication) to allow users to log on and share their details with you.

Once that is done, you can use the [Profile API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api) to access the user's profile. You can access a lot of other things via their well documented [API](http://developer.linkedin.com/apis) as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using php to do this with Pecl

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid doing the OAuth authentication dance, but you can use a callback to do authentication using PHP (thus avoiding making the user input the verification PIN).  The [SimpleLinkedIn PHP library](http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/) has code to do the whole Authentication sequence using callbacks rather than verification PINs.

Comment: Thanks Kirsten, I am php with call back url to avoid the verification pin.